# Recalculate a convolution value with the eager execution

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to use the eager execution.

I create a training set, a weight, and a convolution layer.

I declare the convolution and change the weights.

How can I get the convolution calculated again without having to declare the layer again?

I expected it to be something like that:

```
import tensorflow as tf


tf.enable_eager_execution()    
tfe = tf.contrib.eager


TrainingDataExample = tf.constant(0.5, shape=[8, 5, 6, 1], name="Inputs") 
WeightExample = tfe.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1, 3, 1, 4], seed=1), name="Weights")
ConvExample = tf.nn.conv2d(TrainingDataExample, WeightExample, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID", name="Conv")

NewWeightExample = tf.constant(2.0, shape=[1, 3, 1, 4], name="NewWeights")
WeightExample = tf.assign(WeightExample, NewWeightExample )
result = ConvExample 

print (result)
```

But it does not work, the value of the convolution is not updated.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I do not quite understand what you mean by "without having to declare the layer again".

The method `tf.nn.conv2d` computes a 2-D convolution. That's how to calculate a convolution with TensorFlow.

Now, you earlier evaluated the convolution on `TrainingDataExample` and stored it in `ConvExample`. By generating a new set of weights, `NewWeightExample` and assigning it to override the variable `WeightExample`, **it does not automatically change the value of the convolution earlier calculated in** `ConvExample`.

Hence, you will have to recompute the convolution again, using the new set of weights. You can do this by simply re-running:

```
ConvExample = tf.nn.conv2d(TrainingDataExample, WeightExample,
                           strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID",
                           name="Conv")
```

To get the following result:

```
<tf.Tensor: id=36, shape=(8, 5, 4, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[3., 3., 3., 3.],
         [3., 3., 3., 3.],
         [3., 3., 3., 3.],
         [3., 3., 3., 3.]],
...
```

Comment: What I want to say is without re-computing the convolution with:
    
    `ConvExample = tf.nn.conv2d(TrainingDataExample, WeightExample,
                               strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID",
                               name="Conv")`



There is no other way to do it?

Thank you very much for the reply

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, No. When data is stored in a memory location, the only way to change it is to update it with something else. You can hide how that is done programmatically, but essentially, a recomputation is being carried out.

Comment: There is [`tf.contrib.eager.defun`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/eager/defun) for tracing a function; that'd let you avoid running the Python code every iteration (since it'd get traced and translated into TensorFlow ops for the input shapes/dtypes). You do need to be careful to hold on to the variables outside of it. But it's still doing the computation on each function call.